# PostgreSQL - trying to get UTC modified time

Tags: postgresql, utc, epoch

On all of my tables I have a `modified` column of type `timestamptz` and then a trigger that sets it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` whenever the table is modified.  If I'm running on my local box, which is in the PST timezone, and I make a modification, I see it saying 9:10pm my time.  Now I log into a system in the EDT timezone (3 hours ahead) and query that same column.  Instead of saying 12:10am it's still saying 9:10pm.

That tells me that it is in fact storing a timzeone and isn't just using the epoch value internally.

What's the right thing to be using to store a UTC time whenever this is updated?

My server side is a PHP back-end which grabs the `time()` output, which is supposed to be the epoch value, and then sends that back to the client on each call.  When I call into the server I pass that specific value, and then my SQL query adds an "where modified > to_timestamp(?)" so that I'm only getting items which have been modified since the last time I talked to the server.

Comment: The *system* is in `EDT`, but what timezone is it sending to the database server? `show TimeZone;` . If it's not setting the server `TimeZone` variable in its session to its local timezone, that'd explain it. Many drivers intentionally keep the `TimeZone` set to UTC and work with UTC times.

Comment: OK, that's weird.  It says PST8PDT.

Comment: What client is it? I guess the driver might not be setting `TimeZone` to the local TZ at all. (Personally I think PostgreSQL's server-side timesamp conversion is an unfortunate misfeature, but we're kind of stuck with it).